# i10test for integration/stationary time series

Tags: matlab, time-series

In http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/examples/time-series-regression-iv-spurious-regression.html, I am examing the use of the i10test for integration/stationary time series.  The online help at http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/i10test.html shows that this is done through a series of hypothesis tests.  From my (OK, limited) exposure to hypthothesis testing, there is usually a threshold for the p-value, e.g. the alpha, that is predefined.  Would anyone know if that applies here, and what the value would be?

I've posted this question to:
http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/W6xq-p_ANsQ and
[i10test for integration/stationary time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385811/i10test-for-integration-stationary-time-series)

Comment: It'd be helpful if those who downvoted this question commented on the reason.  Thanks.

Comment: I think the answer is that you can specify the alpha for each test via that iParams and sparams arguments.  Without such a user specification, each test has a default alpha.   The button to "Answer Your Question" doesn't seem to be working, so here it is, in the Comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is that you can specify the alpha for each test via that iParams and sparams arguments. Without such a user specification, each test has a default alpha. The button to "Answer Your Question" doesn't seem to be working, so here it is, in the Comments.